# What is this vehicle locating algorithm doing exactly?

Tags: algorithm, deep-learning

This is an algorithm i found on this [paper](http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/2013papers/gjhy/gh72.pdf) for vehicle detection in satellite images, this algorithm is for a sliding window technique.

[image]

I have a basic idea, but I don't understand how the Vehicle locating windows are created, any help would be great, thanks.

HDNN = Hybrid Deep Neural Network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my interpretation.

1. Divide the image into 32 x 32 pixel images.
2. Calculate the center of all the images.  Collect all of these images.
3. Divide the image into 48 x 48 pixel images.  Repeat step 2.  Divide the image into 64 x 64 pixel images.  Repeat step 2.
4. Filter all of the images and feed the images that pass the filter into the HDNN.  The images are filtered by

   - Rotating every image 11 times by: 0, 4.5, 9, ··· , 45 degrees
   - Shrinking or enlarging the non-rotating images into multi-scalings: 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3.
   - For each generated image, we get four preprocessed images: Gray, Gradient, Gradient1 and Gradient2 (see the (a), (b), (c) of Fig. 1). These preprocessed images are normalized into 48 × 48 size and [0,255] gray range.

All of these rotated, shrunk or enlarged preprocessed images are stored in their database and sent to HDNN.